# Final image has smaller image after merging multiple images

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a big final jpg image from 4 different jpg images. I noticed after adding images onto the final image, the size of the image changes.

The size of the image should remain the same on the final image too.

[image] [image]

Ex- The galaxy image(dark sky) on the final image looks small, compared to the actual image.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
     private void CombineImages()
    {
        string path1 = @"C:\temp\";
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path1);

        //change the location to store the final image.
        FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
        string finalImage = @"C:\\images\\FinalImage3.jpg";
        List<int> imageHeights = new List<int>();
        List<int> imagewidths = new List<int>();
        int nIndex = 0;
        int width = 0;
        int maxHeight = 0;
        int totalHeight = 0;
        bool odd = true;
        bool firstRow = true;

        //to get height and width to create final image
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {

            if (odd)
            {
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                    firstRow = false;
                    imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
                    width += img.Width;
                    img.Dispose();
                    odd = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                    maxHeight = imageHeights.Max();
                    imagewidths.Add(width+100);
                    width = 0;
                    totalHeight = totalHeight + maxHeight+img.Height+100;
                    imageHeights.Clear();
                    imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
                    width += img.Width;
                    img.Dispose();
                    odd = false;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
                width += img.Width;
                img.Dispose();
                odd = true;
            }


        }
        imageHeights.Sort();

        Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(imagewidths.Max(), totalHeight);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);
        g.Clear(Color.Gainsboro);


         imageHeights = new List<int>();
         imagewidths = new List<int>();
         nIndex = 0;
         width = 0;
         maxHeight = 0;
         totalHeight = 0;
         odd = true;
         firstRow = true;

        int imagewidth = 0;

        //actual merging of images
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);

            if (odd)
            {
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(img, 25, 25);
                    firstRow = false;
                    imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
                    width += img.Width;
                    img.Dispose();
                    odd = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    maxHeight = imageHeights.Max();
                    g.DrawImage(img, 25, maxHeight+50);
                    imagewidths.Add(width);
                    width = 0;
                    totalHeight = totalHeight + maxHeight + img.Height;
                    imageHeights.Clear();
                    imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
                    width += img.Width;
                    imagewidth = img.Width;
                    img.Dispose();
                    odd = false;
                }


            }
            else
            {

                imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
                g.DrawImage(img, width+50, maxHeight+50);

                img.Dispose();

                odd = true;
            }

            img.Dispose();
        }
        g.Dispose();
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        img3.Save(finalImage, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        img3.Dispose();

    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a scaling of the image on the screen? While it's a bit hard to read your code, I don't see any place where you'd draw any image with a size different from the original one. The only thing I can suggest is to check if the image resolutions are correct (see a remark on this topic in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawImage_System_Drawing_Image_System_Int32_System_Int32_), under "Remarks").